# filter rows in a pandas dataframe from substrings (keys) in a list and also add new column "key" to dataframe containing the substring matched (key)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, contains, string-matching

Iam new to python. The below code filter rows in a dataframe df based on substrings (keys)  in a list and add a new column  say 'Key" containing the substring (all of them). The dataframe contains name of student, age, sport. The sport page contains all sports played by him. the list array contains two sports names.  The code here extracts the names that play any of the sports mentions in the list. I want another field 'Key' in the dataframe that mentions the matches from list  like "hockey" or " "football" or "jockey football" depending on the match.
'''

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'Joseph','Krish', 'Mohan', 'Ram'], 'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18, 29],'Sport':['football', 'hockey football badminton', 'cricket', 'tennis football', 'hocey cricet']}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
list = ['football','hockey']  # list of sports to filter
list_s = np.array(list)
print(list_s)
#Filter rows from df which are in list_s
dff = df[df['Sport'].str.contains('|'.join(list_s))]
print(dff)
```

Answer (score 1):

While it might be possible in this case to just use substrings, a more robust approach would be to make a new DataFrame that maps each Name to each associated Sport, and select the desired Names from there.

```py
>>> name_to_sport = (
    df[['Name']]
    .join(df['Sport'].str.split())
    .explode('Sport')
)
>>> name_to_sport
     Name      Sport
0     Tom   football
1  Joseph     hockey
1  Joseph   football
1  Joseph  badminton
2   Krish    cricket
3   Mohan     tennis
3   Mohan   football
4     Ram      hocey
4     Ram     cricet
>>> name_to_sport.loc[name_to_sport['Sport'].isin(['football','hockey']), 'Name'].unique()
array(['Tom', 'Joseph', 'Mohan'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Thanks. the data frame posted is just for analogy.  Actual data is large one containing announcement made by companies, which I want to filter based on about a 100  or more  keywords. Right now I iterate it  over a loop for every keyword, just to put it in a column but that may not be optimum way of doing it. I want a  filtered list of announcements with a new column telling me which keywords are contained in the announcement. Hence i need a solution on lines mentioned.

Comment: Let me put actual data  

DF:
Key  News
 Tata Steel results   
        Oracle results, buyback
 Airtel results, dividend:
The keyword List is{ 'result', 'buyback', 'dividend')
df is already filtered from df_large and contains at least one keyword from  list in 'News" col..
used  df = df_large[df_large['News'].str.contains('|'.join(list)]
want  'key'in df to be populated by keyword (one or more) in the List like 
 Key    NEWS 
result   Tata Steel results    
dividend ,buyback    Oracle results, buyback
result, buyback          Airtel result, buyback